# COUNTIFS with multiple Ranges, Single Criteria

Tags: excel

I have the data set below.

```
     A           B           C           D
 1   Apple       Pear        Grape       Orange
 2   Blueberry   Grape
 3   Pear        Orange
 4   Apple       Grape       Orange
 5   Grape       Orange      Blueberry
 6   Pear
 7   Grape       Apple
```

I want to count the rows in which either Apple OR Pear appear.  So the answer to the above should end up being 5 (rows 1,3,4,6 and 7).  Row 1 where both apple and pear appear should only be counted once.  In my actual data set, I have 4 columns and upwards of 250 rows.

Among other attempted solutions, I have tried

```
 =COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"Apple")+COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"Pear")+COUNTIFS(B1:B7,"Apple")+COUNTIFS(B1:B7,"Pear")+COUNTIFS(C1:C7,"Apple")+COUNTIFS(C1:C7,"Pear")+COUNTIFS(D1:D7,"Apple")+COUNTIFS(D1:D7,"Pear")
```

but that double counts row 1 giving one extra count than I am looking for.

If it is simpler, I know how many rows I have, so a solution that involves determining how many rows do not contain either apple or pear would be sufficient.

Comment: You are correct, the post has been edited for this revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$1,ROW(A1:A7)-1,0,1,4),"Apple")+COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$1,ROW(A1:A7)-1,0,1,4),"Pear")>0))
```

If goes row by row and does two COUNTIFS on each Row and adds them together.  If that row is greater than 0 it adds 1 to the SUMPRODUCT.

[image]

Or this that uses MMULT to return the correct Number:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N((A1:D7="Apple")+(A1:D7="Pear")),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:D7)^0))>0))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.

The advantage with this over the first is this one is not Volatile.

[image]

Comment: For whatever, reason, the first formula you provided did not work for my full solution, but the second one worked great.  Thank you!